Polynomial formula for orthogonal vector in odd dimensions
I have been thinking about this problem recently. In 2 dimensions there is an easy formula for a nonzero vector orthogonal to a given vector $(x, y)$, namely $(-y, x)$. By taking pairs of coordinates, this extends to any even dimension, i.e. in four dimensions $(x, y, z, w)$ is orthogonal to $(-y, x, -w, z)$, etc. However, as we live in a $3$-dimensional universe, I was inclined to ask if there is a similar formula to find a nonzero vector orthogonal to a given $(x, y, z)$. The first attempt is to ask if there is a matrix transformation where this is the case, but there is none in odd dimensions as any matrix would have a real eigenvector which cannot map to a nonzero orthogonal vector. So I am led to ask more generally if there exists polynomials $u, v, w$ of $x, y$, and $z$ such that $(u(x, y, z), v(x, y, z), w(x, y, z))$ is always nonzero and orthogonal to $(x, y, z)$, as long as $(x, y, z) \neq (0, 0, 0)$.
I have noticed that this is equivalent to the problem of finding polynomials $u, v, w$ such that $(u, v, w)$ is always not a scalar multiple of $(x, y, z)$, except $(0, 0, 0)$. Clearly if it is nonzero and orthogonal it is not a scalar multiple, and if it is not a scalar multiple we can take the cross product $(u, v, w) \times (x, y, z)$ in three dimensions to get such an orthogonal-generating polynomial. In higher odd dimensions if $\vec{u}$ is the vector of polynomials in the entries of $\vec{v}$ then we could also take $(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}) \vec{u} - (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{u}) \vec{v}$ to get an orthogonal-generating polynomial. In this reformulation, when $\vec{u}$ is only a matrix transformation applied to $\vec{v}$ then we are asking if the matrix has no real eigenvectors, which again is impossible in odd dimensions. So basically the question comes down to if polynomial transformations in odd dimensions also always have an "eigenvector".
I have tried to find such an orthogonal-generating polynomial in 3 dimensions but have not succeeded. Maybe there is an obvious example out there that I haven't found yet but this also seems like the kind of thing that may just be impossible. The only progress I have made so far is that, if such a solution exists, $u$ cannot have a monomial of the form $x^n$ since $x u + y v + z w$ is identically $0$. Then when $y = z = 0$ we must have $u = 0$, but as $(u, v, w) \neq (0, 0, 0)$ one of $v$ or $w$ must have a monomial of the form $x^n$. To cancel in the expression $x u + y v + z w$, this implies $u$ has a monomial of the form $y x^{n-1}$ or $z x^{n-1}$. The same argument also puts some restrictions on $v$ and $w$.
If someone could find an orthogonal-generating polynomial in $3$ dimensions or prove that none exists I would be satisfied. Bonus points if it can generalize to arbitrary odd dimensions.

Can’t happen, by the Hairy Ball theorem, even if we relax to "continuous" instead of "polynomial". See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4400019/how-to-find-a-basis-of-mathbb-rn-if-we-are-given-just-one-vector-using-the-c/4400594#4400594

@TheoBendit Ah, so that's what was preventing me. Looks like this question has been asked before in greater generality.
